# videojs - how to pause a video while hiding interface?

Tags: html, css, video.js

Question: Is it possible to pause a video that autoplays using video.js player, while not displaying the controls of the video?

---

I'm using video.js for a website, and got the video auto-running upon visiting the site.

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{
    "controls": false,
    "loop": "true",
    "autoplay": true, 
    "preload": "true"
    }'>
<source src="vid/gh.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
```

I have decided to hide the controls, so you can only see the video.

Is it possible to click the video to stop it from playing?

I realize by setting the controls to false, I hide the play button and thus remove the option to pause the video.

I'm still at a pretty basic level, so I have no idea whether or not this is even possible - but I'm very curious to hear if there is a way to do it!

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<video width="320" height="240"  onclick="this.pause()" autoplay>
  <source src="{{asset('video/media_.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This will pause your video by clicking on the video. But if you want to play your video again then you need to use the following line in the place of `onclick`:

```
  onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();"
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much! 
EDIT: It would be very cool to be able to play it again upon another click. Would it be too much work?

Comment: It is very easy. I have edited the code. Just follow the last line. I hope you would understand. If any confusion occurs then please don't hesitate to ask again.

Comment: Cool, it works! Do I understand it correctly?:

First it asks if "this" (meaning my video) is paused? If it isn't paused 
then play it, else (if it isn't paused) pause it.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But the first condition checks if it is paused then play. else is just perfect.

Comment: Thanks so much rdhawladar. Great job!